# VSCode / Pylance Problems not showing in the popover when hovering with the mouse

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flake8, pylance

I'm on VS Code Version: 1.62.0 with the Language Server version: v2021.11.0.

When I hover with the mouse on a problem, I can't see linter error messages (e.g., flake8 messages are available just in the problem section at the bottom, but not in the popover). I used to see all of them also in the popover before the latest VSCode update. Here is a pic of the problem in action:

[image]

My related settings are:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": ".venv/bin/python",
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
    "python.linting.enabled": true,
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I am having the same problem, and also with mypy. The pylance error messages show up in the editor popup, but not flake8 or mypy  anymore :(

Comment: It's a bug. Probably, you have just [commented](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17882#issuecomment-972694565) the related issue. Check out also this one: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136711

Comment: Looks fixed in 1.63.0: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17882#issuecomment-972787428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can downgrade to [an older version](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_61) of the VSCode. I met the same problem on `1.62.0` after I downgrade to the early version of `1.61.2`, the problem was solved.

I had submitted a bug on Github, you can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17976).